# What are the dangers of using an unsupported Ubuntu version?

Tags: updates, security, update-manager, software-sources, malware

Non-LTS versions of Ubuntu only receive security updates for up to 9 months after their release (for Ubuntu 15.10, until 07/2016) and are not recommended for use after the expiration of the support.

Would there be an imminent threat for a user, who is generally careful (not adding third-party repositories, using a web browser without JavaScript/NoScript, not executing unknown files/commands, active software firewall) in continuing to run an unsupported version for a few more months (e.g. 3-4 additional months until the release of the next equal month-version, such as .10 to .10)?

If yes, what would be the most likely causes of a security breach?

Comment: If you're running your system in an isolated environment, as in very little internet access, very little access to read-write usb devices (external storage drives) and very little access to human disturbances, then you should be good ... indefinitely (well, actually until your hardware expires or until any of the above situations occurs).

Comment: I can confirm all these cases, except for little internet access. It is a personal computer and would continue to be used at least for internet browsing. In fact, basically the only program that will access the internet in that time will be Firefox (with active NoScript/Privacy Badger on almost every site except those that do not work otherwise e.g. askubuntu, ebay and such).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be safe from viruses and malware, since anti-virus software is 3rd party and you would still be able to update them since the companies that made the software will keep providing you with new virus definitions.

**But**....There are a lot of Linux black-hats out there who would just love to hack into your computer. And because Canonical will no longer give you security updates, your computer will be rendered vulnerable. (Kind of like when MS pulled the plug on Windows XP). I think that programs such as Java and ssh would be targeted to gain full access to your computer. But as long as you harden down your computer, I guess you would be fine for a few months or more after the version no longer becomes supported.

Comment: I just wanted to add, if he did actually use antivirus, it would be most likely unaffected since Ubuntu doesn't do virus definitions, the 3rd party still would regardless of EOL on ubuntu.  Also, any non-ubuntu PPA could still remain updated, so for instance, ppa:webupd8team for JAVA.

Comment: Yah, you're right about that, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not currently use any Antivirus software. I have not contracted any malware for years that I know of (also while using Windows in the past), not opening any spam mail/installing unknown executables and browsing the web mostly with deactivated JavaScript helped greatly in this, from my point of view. That's why I did not bother installing a virus scanner after switching to Ubuntu until this point.

Could you elaborate what exacty you mean with "harden down your computer"?

Comment: Harden down means: A sufficient Firewall, a good anti-virus, close ports that can allow a hacker to gain remote control of your computer, tweak privacy settings, add a easy to remember, good password for your account, and the list just goes on and on.

Answer (score 2):

My question would be a what is the upside? You cannot upgrade from 15.10 to 16.10 directly. If the upgrade is something you don't want to do because you are afraid of maybe breaking something, the LTS version would be the better option due to its longer support.

But as the others wrote, as long as you are careful and don't run services (or even better create your own debs (backports) from the newer releases when there is a problem), you might be fine. Consider using a ppa for the browser to get security fixes at least there.

I guess this comes from some kind of necessity, but if not, never **plan** to do it like this!

Comment: Thanks! It was not planned this way. I installed 15.10 to test a newer version when it was released last year, planning to upgrade to 16.04 as soon as possible. However, parts of my hardware appear to be incompatible to 16.04 and it will be changed later this year any way, although probably only after the 15.10 EOL. To not having to roll-back to 14.04 or wasting time that I don't really have at the moment, trying to install and set up a working 16.04 for a few weeks until changing the system again, I wanted to find out just how dangerous it would be to use the current system a little longer.